# Output in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing some code in my controller, and I was wondering if I can just run my controller, so I can see if my code is working properly?

Something like this

```
    public void Index()
    {

        int a = 4;
        int b = 3;
        int result = a * b;

        output(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is to know **How to unit test MVC application** and you also may not want to have void controller in the application.

You can find lot of articles on this topic. I have just listed a couple here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/763928/MVC-Unit-Testing-Unleashed

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify it a bit and return a `ContentResult` though.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   int a = 4;
   int b = 3;
   int result = a * b;

   return Content(result.ToString());        
}
```

And you can access it via your browser and see the result